IBM Quantum payload error
I've received the following error on one of the circuits I'm running on IBM Quantum devices (on IBM Brisbane) using EstimatorV2 primitive.
Failed - Too large of job payload being loaded. Reduce the length of the program data being loaded.

I am unclear what program data this error message is referring to. The circuit I'm running has around 600 ECR gates, and the Hamiltonian has around 5000 Pauli strings. Am I reaching a hard coded bound on the circuit depth, or is there a way to get around this error?

You are receiving this error because according to qiskit one of the following in your circuit is too large:

circuit depth
number of shots

Circuit depth: You can try to divide your job into batches so that the circuit size is small and can be loaded onto the real device. To divide the jobs into batches I would recommend you to take a look at this.
Number of shots: For qiskit, the highest number of shots that you can specify is 10000. Anything more that this will likely result in an error.
Other than these two, if your circuits are too large sometimes you might get a time-out error.
